# Convert a Regular C styled coding file to GNU style coding standards

Tags: c, regex, vim, coding-style, gnu

I have a file which I have written in "Regular C style".  for example

```
void foo()
{
    if(;;) {
        ....
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

wanted to change this style to GNU style coding using vim or some other plugin

```
void foo()
{
    if(;;)
      {
        ....
      }
    else
      {
        ....
      }
}
```

Wanted to ask if there can be a quick shortcut to do it so that it detects the loops starting braces and brings it below and indents it by 2 spaces.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: GNU style coding is documented very well here :-  https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/c-coding-style.html.en

Comment: Open an emacs buffer in C mode with gnu style minor mode and paste your code in. Save it and exit.

Answer (score 1):

The correct tool for that job is [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/), which was created exactly for the purpose of re-indenting existing C code. In particular, you might want to look at the option `--gnu-style`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick answer, probably not the best: you can insert the line breaks, select the whole document and re-indent with:

```
:1,$s/\v(\S) *\{/\1^M{/g
:1,$s/\v\} *(\S)/}^M\1/g
:1
VG=
```

Of course, this depends on your vim configuration (the `=` command, for instance, depends on your definition of `equalprg`). Moreover, this treats the comments like normal code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.